# Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted Assembley

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64

I was trying to implement Hello world program in Assembly, but there is some warning:
To implement I used

```
as -gstabs helloasm.s -o helloasm.o
```

The Warning:

> helloasm.s: Assembler messages:
>       helloasm.s: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted

There is code below:

```
.global _start
.data
  message:.ascii "Hello World\n"
.text
_start:
  movq $1, %rax
  movq $1, %rdi
  movq $message, %rsi
  movq $13, %rdx
  syscall
  movq $60, %rax
  xorq %rdi, %rdi
  syscall
```

So, how can I resolve this warning?

Comment: By adding a newline at the end of the file !?

Comment: How can we do that in code? Because, I am new at assembly.

Comment: You don't do that in code. You just add a newline at the end of your source file and the warning will magically disappear.

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the comments at the time of the question, this warning can be resolved by making sure that the Assembly source file ends in a newline.

Comment: It doesn't need to end with an empty line; that would mean there are two `\n` characters at the end of the file.  1 is the minimum, 0 will produce this warning.  (e.g. if `cat foo.s` prints the next prompt on the same line as `syscall`, like if you did `echo -n syscall`, then you have that problem.  Assuming your shell doesn't automagically handle it and print the prompt on a new line anyway.)

Comment: Basically a Stack Overflow code block can't represent text that doesn't end with a newline so its impossible to show the problem in a copy/pastable way; you could `tail -1 | hexdump -C` to show the difference.

Comment: Thanks, you're right - I've removed that example since it's inaccurate.

Comment: Why do we have to end an assembly code with a newline?